# Monitoring virtual host on ESX5 with Nagios

Tags: monitoring, nagios, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

My question is how to monitor with Nagios, the performance and availiability (machine stopped) of several virtual hosts running in a ESX. All plugins I've found are for 3.x API, running commands or with SNMP, but none of these methods are valid with the Vmware ESX 5.0

Comment: If you're asking "How do I monitor the ESX hosts?", the answer is in the duplicate we've pointed you to. If you're asking "How do I monitor the virtual machines?" cross out the word virtual and see if you know the answer (treat them just like any physical host).

Answer (score 0):

The CIM health checking python scripts all still work but the user must be an Administrator in ESXi.

Otherwise you can always monitor the virtual servers/services themselves.